# Unequal page margins

Tags: margins, paper-size

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=11.69in,paperwidth=8.27in]{geometry}
\geometry{vmargin={1.4in,0.3in},hmargin={1.4in,1.4in},footskip=20pt}

\newcommand{\header}[1]{{
\hspace*{-15pt}\vspace*{6pt} \textsc{#1}} \vspace*{-6pt} 
\lineunder
}

\newcommand{\lineunder}{
\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-18pt} 
\hrulefill \\
}

\begin{document}
\header{Blablabla}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following document:

[image]

When I print out the document on an A4 paper, the left margin is 3 centimetres wide and the right one is 3.5 centimetres despite me setting them to an equal size  (`hmargin={1.4in,1.4in}` in line 3). What is causing the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could this be your printer, or a driver issue? When I compile your document I get the same margins on both sides. Add the  `showframe` option to geometry and look at the PDF on your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you want to achieve. If you're trying to set a page header, you should use `fancyhdr` or similar package.

Anyway, this produces equal spaces on either side. Beware of unprotected endlines; you have very strange `\vspace` instructions.

I replaced the complicated lengths in inches by the simpler `a4paper` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{vmargin={1.4in,0.3in},hmargin={1.4in,1.4in},footskip=20pt}

\newcommand{\header}[1]{%
\noindent\textsc{#1}\\[-6pt]\mbox{}\hrulefill\par
}

\begin{document}

\header{Blablabla}

\end{document}
```

[image]